# Error trying to get v.exe to print help information

Tags: vlang

Is the "help" for the v.exe command not yet implemented? I am getting this:

```
c:\v>.\v.exe help
error: unknown help topic "default". Use `v help` for usage information.
Known help topics:

c:\v>
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. You can file a bug report at https://github.com/vlang/v/issues about it.

Comment: works fine for me on Windows, `v version >>> 0.4.3 vd145b2`

Comment: @FObersteiner I will have to download that version (Nov 11, 2023
V 0.4.3 is out!) . I have "V 0.4.2 1c4c505" (Sep 30, 2023 V 0.4.2 is out!)

Comment: Btw. you shouldn't need to download a new version "manually" if you have `v` set up; just run `v.exe up` to update to the latest version from their github (I've just tested this on Windows).

Comment: Hello! Since you were able to solve the error by updating to a newer version of V, could you add a self-answer and mark it as answered?

Comment: @HungryBlueDev done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happened with version **0.4.2** 1c4c505 . I get the correct output from V **0.4.3** e8ce02b . 0.4.3 was released on November 11. Thanks to user FObersteiner for pointing out the error was not in 0.4.3 .